# R: Sum column from table 2 based on value in table 1, and store result in table 1

Tags: r, merge, sapply, sumifs

I am a R noob, and hope some of you can help me.

I have two data sets:
- store (containing store data, including location coordinates (x,y). The location are integer values, corresponding to GridIds)
- grid (containing all gridIDs (x,y) as well as a population variable TOT_P for each grid point)

What I want to achieve is this:
For each store I want loop over the grid date, and sum the population of the grid ids close to the store grid id.

I.e basically SUMIF the grid population variable, with the condition that

```
grid(x) < store(x) + 1 & 
grid(x) > store(x) - 1 & 
grid(y) < store(y) + 1 &
grid(y) > store(y) - 1
```

How can I accomplish that? My own take has been trying to use different things like merge, sapply, etc, but my R inexperience stops me from getting it right.

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
Sample data:

```
StoreName   StoreX  StoreY
Store1  3   6
Store2  5   2

TOT_P   GridX   GridY
8   1   1
7   2   1
3   3   1
3   4   1
22  5   1
20  6   1
9   7   1
28  1   2
8   2   2
3   3   2
12  4   2
12  5   2
15  6   2
7   7   2
3   1   3
3   2   3
3   3   3
4   4   3
13  5   3
18  6   3
3   7   3
61  1   4
25  2   4
5   3   4
20  4   4
23  5   4
72  6   4
14  7   4
178 1   5
407 2   5
26  3   5
167 4   5
58  5   5
113 6   5
73  7   5
76  1   6
3   2   6
3   3   6
3   4   6
4   5   6
13  6   6
18  7   6
3   1   7
61  2   7
25  3   7
26  4   7
167 5   7
58  6   7
113 7   7
```

The output I am looking for is

```
StoreName   StoreX  StoreY  SUM_P
Store1  3   6   479
Store2  5   2   119
```

I.e for store1 it is the sum of TOT_P for Grid fields X=[2-4] and Y=[5-7]

Comment: Are you merging on a gridID column or on two columns (x & y)?

Comment: I would need to join on two columns, since the join need to return all values where the grid x,y are between [store-2 ;store+2]..i.e. I have one grid cell as store location, and need to return/evaluate the 25 cells of the grid centered around the store.

Comment: @caz777 If you can provide sample data and specify your desired output then it would be easy for us to help you solve this problem. Thanks!

Comment: @prem I added sample data to the bottom om the original post, and changed the requirement to only look for grid ids +-1 instead of +-2

Comment: Since location co-ordinates are integer and you are checking `grid(x) < store(x) + 1 & grid(x) > store(x) - 1 & grid(y) < store(y) + 1 & grid(y) > store(y) - 1` then it should result into one-to-one mapping (between store & grid) as per your sample example and desired output will become `Store1  3   6   3` & `Store2  5   2   12`. Suggest you to re-verify your sample example.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use `dplyr` to calculate the difference between each store and all grid points and then group and sum based on these new columns.

```
#import library
library(dplyr)

#create example store table
StoreName<-paste0("Store",1:2)
StoreX<-c(3,5)
StoreY<-c(6,2)
df.store<-data.frame(StoreName,StoreX,StoreY)

#create example population data (copied example table from OP)
df.pop

#add dummy column to each table to enable cross join
df.store$k=1
df.pop$k=1

#dplyr to join, calculate absolute distance, filter and sum    
df.store %>%
  inner_join(df.pop, by='k') %>%
  mutate(x.diff = abs(StoreX-GridX), y.diff=abs(StoreY-GridY)) %>%    
  filter(x.diff<=1, y.diff<=1) %>%
  group_by(StoreName) %>%
  summarise(StoreX=max(StoreX), StoreY=max(StoreY), tot.pop = sum(TOT_P) ) 

#output:
  StoreName StoreX StoreY tot.pop
     <fctr>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <int>
1    Store1      3      6     721
2    Store2      5      2     119
```

Comment: thanks, I added sample data at the original post, as well as changing the requirement to only look for id+-1 instead of +- 2

Comment: it might become an issue memory wise, but not sure if it is possible to completely avoid. My grid table has 2mio+ rows, and the store one has around 1000 rows....however later on I might need to do it for a much larger set of "store" rows.